# How to make a fixed background website scale?

Tags: html, background, scaling

So I've managed to set up a website for a new app company I'm working on, wherein I'm using a big image since its easier to set up quickly for me, but when the browser size adjusts it squishes. Is there a way to make it so that the image scales? Here is the code in my index.html file. Thanks so much for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>WeShould Inc</title>
<style type="text/css">

<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y:hidden;}
body {overflow-y:auto;}
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
#content {position:static;padding:10px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-background"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DJaWd.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Fireworks"></div>
    <div id="content">

    </div> */


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a jQuery plugin. There are a lot of them, here's an example. http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image

Comment: Sorry for being the biggest n00b ever, but the two pieces of code in the site you sent me, where in here do I put them? All I have is an index.html file, do I need anther file for the JQuery script? Thanks so much.

Comment: Check the demo page of the script http://nooshu.com/explore/scalable-background/. All you need is there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html { 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DJaWd.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://i.imgur.com/DJaWd.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
</style>
```

That should work for all browsers, including IE.

Example of use- http://fiddle.jshell.net/FENXB/1/show/